# Amplify get owner user attributes from Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**Background:**
I'm using Amplify to create a `type Item @model` GraphQL datastore with an `@auth allow owner` which adds the owner as an CognitoID to the Item.

**Question:**
This item is readable for guests and I would like to show the owner (or other related metadata such as a username/email) for this item.

e.g. `Cognito.GetUserAttributes(2b10fb7e-4472-43c9-9bb9-54219b5027a3)`

Is somthing like this possible? How is this supposed to be designed for this use case? Do I have to add a lambda that adds the user meta data to the item when it is created?

I would like this solution to be scalable.

---

The schema:

```
type Item
@model
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner},
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
    { allow: private, operations: [read] },
    { allow: public, operations: [read] }
])
{
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String
}
```

From DynamoDB:

```
{
  "__typename": "Item",
  "_lastChangedAt": 1593707126605,
  "_version": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-07-02T16:25:26.582Z",
  "description": "Description",
  "id": "0592fcd8-408e-406e-84bf-9f63eb43e147",
  "owner": "2b10fb7e-4472-43c9-9bb9-54219b5027a3",
  "title": "Item",
  "updatedAt": "2020-07-02T16:25:26.582Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function resolver on a `cognitoAttributes` field. The lambda function can call admin-get-user in `Cognito` and return the attributes. The lambda function will receive the dynamo Item in the `event.source` property so you will have access to the owner id to make the call to `Cognito`.

```
type Item
@model
@auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner},
    { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] },
    { allow: private, operations: [read] },
    { allow: public, operations: [read] }
])
{
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    cognitoAttributes: [String]! @function('cognitoGetUserAttributes-${env})
    description: String
}
```